# Angular 6 calling function after dialog close

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

I am trying to implement a function call after closing the dialog, but I can not use the pipe nor subscribe it. Let's see my code.

i got this error :

```
Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'MatDialogRef<any, any>'.   Property '_overlayRef' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'
```

the idea is to call the function `this.windowScrolling.disable ();` when to close the dialog

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavegarService {
  public offsets: number[];

   windowScrolling: WindowScrollingService;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              windowScrolling: WindowScrollingService,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef <any, any>,
              private dialog: MatDialog) {

    this.windowScrolling = windowScrolling;
    this.offsets = this.range( 1, 20 );
  }

  navegarContext(url: string, event: any = null) {
    this.router.navigate([url], {queryParams: {context: this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['context']}});
  }

  navegar(url: string, event: any = null) {
    this.router.navigate([url]);
  }

  abrirModal(component: ComponentType<any>, dados: any, event: any = null): MatDialogRef<any, any> {
    this.windowScrolling.disable();
    return this.dialog.open(component, {minWidth: '90%', disableClose: true, data: dados, position: {top: '4%'}}).afterClosed()
      .pipe(); // got error here
  }

  private range( from: number, to: number ): number[] {
    const values = [];
    for ( let i = from ; i <= to ; i++ ) {
      values.push( i );
    }
    return( values );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message pretty much says exactly what's wrong: the object you're returning from the method is not the correct type.

---

To fix this, we need to create and store off the new dialog, then create the subscription, and finally return the dialog object that we just created.

```
abrirModal(component: ComponentType<any>, dados: any, event: any = null): MatDialogRef<any, any> {
    this.windowScrolling.disable();

    // Create and store dialog object
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(component, {minWidth: '90%', disableClose: true, data: dados, position: {top: '4%'}});

    // Create subscription
    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
        // Do stuff after the dialog has closed
        this.windowScrolling.disable();
    });

    // Return dialog object
    return dialog;
}
```